# Update Angular child 1.5 component not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

I am using an Angular 1.5 component to build the below structure:

```
<parent>
    <child active="model.active">
    <child active="model.active">
    <child active="model.active">
</parent>
```

My component:

```
(function() {
'use strict' 
angular.module('module').component('child',
    {
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        bindings: {
            active: '<'
        },
        controllerAs: 'model',
        controller: function() {

            var model = this;

            model.select = function() {
                model.deselectAllChildren()(model);
                model.active = true;
            };
        }
    });
})();
```

Parent `deselectAllChildren` method:

```
model.deselectAllChildren = function(tabModel) {
    model.active = false;
};
```

When a user selects one of the child components, I want it to be made active and the other children inactive. So the logic makes all children inactive (to clean up previous selections) then makes the selected child active. The parent's `model.active` property is false by default. This works fine for the first select but subsequent selects don't work as the previously selected children don't deselect as the `model.active = false` change is not propagating to the child components (because the parent's `model.active` value is still `false` - but some of the children `model.active` equals `true`. This no doubt is a scope/binding issue; I feel like I need to force push `model.active = false` down to all children. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<parent>
    <child active="model.active === 0" on-select="model.active=0">
    <child active="model.active === 1" on-select="model.active=1">
    <child active="model.active === 2" on-select="model.active=2">
</parent>
```

```
angular.module('module').component('child',
{
    templateUrl: 'template.html',
    bindings: {
        active: '<',
        onSelect: '&'
    },
    controllerAs: 'model',
    controller: function() {

        var model = this;

        model.select = function() {
            model.onSelect();
       };
    }
});
```